# Passing values between requests cleanly (in session, as GET/POST parameters... ?)

Tags: php, frameworks, session-variables, web-frameworks

I don't like having to explicitly manage values in session and I can't imagine I'm alone in this... so I wanted to get feedback on:

1. How other programmers/platforms/frameworks handle this
2. The method I use (explained below)

The method I use involves a controller-type script that supports adding a variable in session when I know it may be needed in the next request... and automatically removes it afterwards (the TTL is controlled through a counter).

For example,

- Request 1 - script adds a value to the session with key `selectedValue`
- Request 2 - script reads `selectedValue` from the session
- Request 3 - `selectedValue` is gone from the session (this is OK because it's no longer needed)

This is the cleanest way I can think of **passing** values through different requests, as opposed to storing **global** variables in session (e.g., an authenticated user ID).

In this scenario, a page refresh is ignored, and if a value needs to be passed through to further requests, it needs to be set again.

Comment: Would you mind voting the answers that helped you up and maybe accept one of them?

Comment: Hi @markus! Thanks for your interest, but the answers so far haven't helped me much. There's nothing new here - I thought this problem would be solved elegantly somewhere, maybe it hasn't, or maybe I can't find it. Or maybe it isn't a problem ?!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing it in the session, you could also just pass it as a request parameter to the subsequent request. Assuming that you're using forms for this, the `<input type="hidden">` useful for this.

E.g.

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($foo)?>" />
</form>
```

You can retain it by `$_POST['foo']` then.

Comment: That's okay, as long as it's also okay for the client to modify that value. In many cases, that's not a good alternative for storing in the session.

Answer (score 1):

I went the hidden field route after having bad experiences debugging $_SESSION related issues, however now that I'm more experienced I think session variables are the better way to go.  I'd rather explicitly manage values in $_SESSION than do essentially the same thing with hidden fields where you have to re-encode that information at every page load if you want to retain it over multiple refreshes.